# How can I find the key-value pairs that have smallest value in Spark-streaming?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

I need to find the smallest value and return its key in Stream.
But I have no idea how to do it, I searched API documents but find nothing, would someone like to teach me how to do it?

Comment: I don't think this kind of question is appropriate here, you should do your research and ask for solutions to specific problems, not general like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
>>> stream = ssc.queueStream([sc.parallelize([("a", 1), ("b", 2)])])
>>> stream.map(lambda x: (x[1], x[0])).reduce(min).map(lambda x: x[1]).pprint()
```